# i am trying to develop a test runner in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, test-runner

Any pointers ? Suggestions ? Opinions ?

I am thinking here is a draft specification:

1. Can run individual test methods
2. Can run a single Test Class
3. Rsult in XML
4. Result in HTML
5. Dry-run
6. Calculate and display time taken by each test case, and overall time.
7. Timeout for test cases
8. TAP type test results
9. Log Levels
10. Create Skeleton test cases
11. Coverage
12. Be able to run on a remote host (maybe)
13. Test Reports
14. Command line Help (--help)

Now, where do i start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [py.test](http://pytest.org/)?  Those projects implement a lot of the features that you describe.  It might be easier to write an extension for one of those projects rather than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [green](https://github.com/CleanCut/green).  I wrote it after I got frustrated with nose refusing to accept my pull requests to fix bugs, among other reasons.